# Is there an IDE which can compile old C++ programs?

Tags: c++, ide, compiler

I was taught the old version of C++ in school -- the one which uses iostream.h instead of iostream. I can't use iostream and namespace stuff. I am seeking an IDE which can compile my programs in that old style C++.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Eclipse for that, which will use g++ to compile your code. If you want to use a specific g++ version, you can always install different versions of g++ in your system and force Eclipse to use a specific one to compile.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CodeBlocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/) , this is an IDE to compile,build and debug your C/C++ programs